# MySQL Delete all rows except newest one for each id

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

I have a table named `devices_last_insert`

[image]

The database gets data updates for a few devices (around 4 different `device_id`) and stores them in another table.

In `devices_last_insert` table I want to save the last timestamp for each device.
At the moment it saves every row, as you can see here:

[image]

The trigger that adds the data to this table is written in the table that gets the data:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO devices_last_insert(devices_last_insert.timestamp, 
  devices_last_insert.device_id)
  VALUES(NEW.timestamp, NEW.device);
END
```

I want to change the trigger so it will add a row, if the `device_id` doesn't exist in `devices_last_insert` with the timestamp (the row from the original table has a `timestamp` column), and will update the timestamp if the `device_id` already exists in `devices_last_insert`.
The problem is that `NEW` cannot be used in `DELETE` queries.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I use MySQL. I updated the question now, thank you for noticing.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually delete old records, MySQL can do the heavy lifting for you.
You could create a unique index (or primary key) on the `device_id`, and then use the insert on duplicate syntax:

```
INSERT INTO devices_last_insert 
(devices_last_insert.timestamp, devices_last_insert.device_id)
VALUES (NEW.timestamp, NEW.device)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp = VALUES(timestamp)
```

Comment: @Maya This solution seems to be optimal. If it is safe for you then mark it as accepted. PS. If `device_id` and `timestamp` are the only columns in the table I'd recommend REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT ODKU.